# Will new stars stop forming at some point of time?

Tags: star, nebula, star-formation

New stars keep forming in the universe thanks to all the nebulae. Now, we need Hydrogen to form stars and there would a time when all the hydrogen will get exhausted, and no more star formation will take place, theoretically.

Will there practically be such a point of time? I guess there is no place where hydrogen is replenished after star formation. Or is there a feedback cycle?

Comment: There is no feedback cycle, there will be a point where no stars form anymore, [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy#Cosmology) dictates it.

Comment: @EduardoSerra To be more precise, there is a feedback cycle, but it is a negative feedback rather than a positive. Entropy is the law of decreasing returns essentially.

Comment: Who deleted my comment? There is a positive feedback cycle, which is very weak though. Protons and antiprotons can be produced in black hole evaporation as a side product.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Cosmic GDP has already crashed](http://phys.org/news/2012-11-cosmic-gdp-star-formation-slumps.html), as Peak Star was ~11 billion years ago.
[image: Cosmic GDP]

According to [Sobral et al](http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.3436)'s prediction, the future star production by mass will give only 5% of the stars in the universe today, "even if we wait forever." More theoretical predictions, such as [this one](http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9701131), suggest that nebulae will run out of hydrogen on the order of $10^{13}$ years, while star formation will occasionally happen due to collision of brown dwarfs until somewhere on the order of $10^{14}$ years.

Of course, hydrogen itself may have a finite lifetime. The half-life of a proton is experimentally known to be longer than $10^{34}$ years, but it may still be quite finite.

Comment: I thought I remembered reading something about this, but I couldn't remember where so I left it to someone else to answer. +1

Comment: Very well explained. Exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @called2voyage Brian Cox did a nice show on this in his "Wonders of the Universe" series, but if I recall, he got a bit poetic in specifying the time frames involved. Basically a really really really long time.

Comment: Could it be that at after a certain time, the "dark matter" observed, will become hydrogen? Perhaps after such a long time, that we could never observe it close enough?

Comment: @frodeborli: If it were the case, that would shift the "no more new stars" date upwards. But there's no reason to believe it.

Comment: @StanLiou I agree that there's no reason to believe it. It's just an idea. I think ideas are important, and sometimes worth to explore.

Comment: @frodeborli, a very interesting idea, by the way. Indeed, how do we know if DM particles are stable.

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick Thank you; it would seem to make the universe a continuous flow instead of something with a beginning and an end, which is a somewhat pleasing thought. How can I find out if somebody else have explored the idea before?

Comment: @frodeborli: As dark matter particle hasn't been identified, I don't think anybody considered its lifetimes, except for that they are obviously longer than Hubble time. But you can surely ask a question here on on Physics SE. By the way, http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.6434 .

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick I did at http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1435/could-dark-matter-be-unstable.

Answer (score 2):

Given what we know of entropy and of the expansion of the Universe, the answer to your question is of course "Yes".

It will take a really really long time, however.

Edited to add:

"...a really really long time..." is an intentionally vague description.  Whether it is 10<sup>10</sup> or 10<sup>10<sup>10</sup></sup> Hubble times is open to question.

Comment: Could you be a little bit more precise and indicate, what do you really mean by really really long? Is it several Hubble times, or $10^{10}$ Hubble times, or $10^{10^{10}}$?

Comment: How precise do you need it, @AlexeyBobrick?

Comment: As precise as possible :)

Comment: OK, @AlexeyBobrick, how about 983.98332 x 10^10  Hubble times?

Comment: Nice, but not very convincing, sorry.

Comment: Not very convincing?  I am devastated.  :)

Comment: Well, to share something positive, here is an artists impression of a multiverse: http://www.physicsoftheuniverse.com/images/bigbang_multiverse.jpg , enjoy!